# Running App with locked Screen ios 9

Tags: ios9

I am new IOS developer using swift. I have created   audio song App . I want to make it to run in the background when user minimize the app or do some other stuff. Right now, it stops streaming audio as soon as sent to background and continuous again as soon as it is brought to foreground.

I searched few articles and other forums, but couldn't find any help. I am really new to IOS9 development and don't know about controls/functions in the AppDelegate.swift etc applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

You'll want the 'audio' mode

Comment: no i want to play songs  while screen is locked .

Comment: Should be able to play while the screen is locked. There are lots of audio apps that do that. Need to implement that background mode.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html    ...yeah i got it from this link shim